# serenity with jbehave - JBehave reports do not have any style sheet formating

Tags: serenity-bdd

for test automation we are using serenity with jbehave.
when we run the appropriate maven goal from Eclipse, it creates proper serenity reports.

Issue - JBehave reports created under "target/JBehave" folder are without any formatting. there are no table boundries, no JBehave title image at the top and failed scenarios are not shows in red font.

Is there any way to change the POM.xml or change the code so that JBehave report (with proper formatting) is created along with serenity reports.

Comment: can you past your pom.xml code

Comment: it is same as any other serenity-jbehave project. you can take a sample project from github for serenity-jbehave.

Comment: I tried adding goal to POM.xml file for "run story as embbeddable. this creates the JBheave report with proper format but serenity report is not populated at all and shows zero test runs.    there should be a way to run serenity-jbehave integration tests in such a way that both serenity and Jbehave reports are generated and JBehave report has all the formatting.